What is the length of an algebraic curve?
The following question seems to be somewhat standard, but I was unable to find any reference. I would be grateful for any pointers to relevant literature.
We consider a real polynomial $p(x,y)$ of degree $d$ in the two real variables $x$ and $y$ that does not identically vanish ($p(x,y) \not\equiv 0$).
Obviously, the zero set $$Z = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid p(x,y) = 0\}$$ of $p$ consists of  finitely many curves and isolated points. In particular, it may contain curves of infinite length, e.g., for $p(x,y) = x - y$.
However, we ask the following:

Can we find an upper bound on the maximum length (w.r.t. the usual Euclidean metric) of all these zero curves if we restrict to a compact disk $$D_r(0) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \le r^2\},$$ i.e., can we find an upper bound on the total length of all curves in $Z \cap D_r(0)$ depending on $d$ and $r$?

Can we at least prove that the length in 1. is finite?


This question is related to the earlier posed question What is the longest algebraic curve?, but there is no proof or reference.

That's not a research question. The limit in 1 is infinite unless you bound the degree. Just consider polynomials in the form y-P(x). Since you may approximate the graph of any continuous function by such curve, you may get arbitrary long curve. An algebraic curve is rectifiable, so the length of a compact subset is finite.

Thanks for your answer.  Would you have a reference for that algebraic curves are rectifiable?

Let me just clarify the proof Boris Bukh was thinking of in the question you link. Let $d$ be the degree of the curve, then the length of $Z \cap D_r(0)$ is at most $\pi r d$.
Consider a series of parallel lines in the plane a distance $2r$ apart. Randomly translate and rotate $Z \cap D_r(0)$ in the plane and count how many lines it intersects. On the one hand, by the Buffon's noodle argument, this is $\frac{2L}{2\pi r} =\frac{L}{\pi R}$ where $L$ is the arc length of $Z \cap D_r(0)$. On the other hand, only one line can intersect every translated rotated $D_r(0)$, and each line intersects $Z$ at most $d$ times, $d$ the degree of $Z$, so this expectation is at most $d$. Hence $$\frac{L}{\pi r} \leq d$$ and thus $L \leq \pi r d$.
This bound is sharp as the union of $d/2$ circles of radius slightly less than $r$ shows.

Note also that, while the union of $d/2$ circles of radius $r$ will have a lot of nodes, a small generic perturbation of this example will be a smooth curve of degree $d$ which also approaches the bound.

@DavidESpeyer I was thinking of a union of concentric circles of different radii, which is smooth in the affine plane, but the perturbation trick you give will handle also the singularities at infinity.

Thanks for the explanation!  Do you know if/where this can be found in the literature?
